# boost units parsing string stream

Tags: c++, string, parsing, boost, units-of-measurement

The boost units library provides useful compile time "units of measure" type checking. It also provides stream io operations to serialize units. However, I am struggling with the string parsing bit. 
For example, the following lines:

```
boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::force> f(2.0 * boost::units::si::newton);
std::cout << "Force = " << f << std::endl;
```

produce the output:

```
Force = 2.0 N
```

Can someone point me to an example that parses these standard serialization back to boost units?

```
// f.parse_string("2.0 N");  or using stream operators??
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's not directly supported by the library.

There's an example that could give some inspiration: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_units/Examples.html#boost_units.Examples.RuntimeUnits

> This example shows how to implement an interface that allow different
>   units at runtime while still maintaining type safety for internal
>   calculations.
>
> ```
> namespace {
>
> using namespace boost::units;
> using imperial::foot_base_unit;
>
> std::map<std::string, quantity<si::length> > known_units;
>
> }
>
> quantity<si::length> calculate(const quantity<si::length>& t)
> {
>     return(boost::units::hypot(t, 2.0 * si::meters));
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>     known_units["meter"] = 1.0 * si::meters;
>     known_units["centimeter"] = .01 * si::meters;
>     known_units["foot"] =
>         conversion_factor(foot_base_unit::unit_type(), si::meter) * si::meter;
>
>     std::string output_type("meter");
>     std::string input;
>
>     while((std::cout << "> ") && (std::cin >> input))
>     {
>         if(!input.empty() && input[0] == '#')
>         {
>             std::getline(std::cin, input);
>         }
>         else if(input == "exit")
>         {
>             break;
>         }
>         else if(input == "help")
>         {
>             std::cout << "type \"exit\" to exit\n"
>                 "type \"return 'unit'\" to set the return units\n"
>                 "type \"'number' 'unit'\" to do a simple calculation"
>                 << std::endl;
>         }
>         else if(input == "return")
>         {
>             if(std::cin >> input)
>             {
>                 if(known_units.find(input) != known_units.end())
>                 {
>                     output_type = input;
>                     std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     std::cout << "Unknown unit \"" << input << "\""
>                          << std::endl;
>                 }
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 break;
>             }
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 double value = boost::lexical_cast<double>(input);
>
>                 if(std::cin >> input)
>                 {
>                     if(known_units.find(input) != known_units.end())
>                     {
>                         std::cout << static_cast<double>(
>                             calculate(value * known_units[input]) /
>                             known_units[output_type])
>                             << ' ' << output_type << std::endl;
>                     }
>                     else
>                     {
>                         std::cout << "Unknown unit \"" << input << "\""
>                             << std::endl;
>                     }
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     break;
>                 }
>             }
>             catch(...)
>             {
>                 std::cout << "Input error" << std::endl;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```